# Addig form fields to a custom user model in django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-custom-user

I'm going through the [django for beginners book](https://djangoforbeginners.com/), testing the code from the chapter 8 about the [Custom user model](https://github.com/wsvincent/djangoforbeginners/tree/master/ch8-custom-user-model). The goal is to add the field `age` in the auth user model by subclassing the `AbstractUser` model.

First we create out `CustomUser` in `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Then creating `CustomUserCreationFrom` and `CustomUserChangeFrom` in `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationFrom(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('age',)

class CustomUserChangeFrom(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

And finally, the `CustomUserAdmin` in `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationFrom, CustomUserChangeFrom
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationFrom
    form = CustomUserChangeFrom
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['username', 'email', 'age', 'is_staff',]

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

And of course telling django about our custom auth model in `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

---

Logged as a super user, and when trying to add a new user, there is no field `age` in the creation form.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try adding your field 'age' in list_display in admin?

Comment: @NitinPawar yes, in `CustomUserAdmin` (subclass of UserAdmin), I added age in the list_display

Comment: Oh yeah. Overlooked it.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Michael Herman for this answer: 
https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/

In `CustomUserAdmin` in `admin.py` you have to declare a `fieldsets`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_staff', 'is_active')}
        ),
    )

    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```